# psutil.AccessDenied when using StanfordCoreNLP in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stanford-nlp, python-2.x

```
# coding=utf-8

from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'/Users/silas/stanford-corenlp/', lang='zh')

sentence = '清华大学位于北京。'
print nlp.word_tokenize(sentence)
print nlp.pos_tag(sentence)
print nlp.ner(sentence)
print nlp.parse(sentence)
print nlp.dependency_parse(sentence)

nlp.close()
```

I'm using Mac. Java, NLKT, and Stanforcorenlp toolkit are all ready. When I'm testing the project, the error came out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 5, in <module>
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'/Users/silas/stanford-corenlp/', lang='zh')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stanfordcorenlp/corenlp.py", line 79, in __init__
    if port_candidate not in [conn.laddr[1] for conn in psutil.net_connections()]:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 2120, in net_connections
    return _psplatform.net_connections(kind)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 255, in net_connections
    cons = Process(pid).connections(kind)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 347, in wrapper
    raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
psutil._exceptions.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=25422)
```

I guess it is because the Pycharm project isn't running under a root user. But how can I configure the IDE to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you look at the psutil project in _psosx.py, under net_connections, line 243 says..

> Note: on macOS this will fail with AccessDenied unless the process is owned by root.

That means that you'll need to run as root by doing something like `sudo pycharm.sh`.

If you don't want to run your entire IDE as root, there's a few examples on SO on how you can run a specific script with super-user privileges.  For instance see [Debugging in pyCharm with sudo privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299509/debugging-in-pycharm-with-sudo-privileges).

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be specific to Mac OS X which would not allow Python to check the current port.

Comment this portion of code of corenlp.py file:

```
        if self.port is None:
        for port_candidate in range(9000, 65535):
            if port_candidate not in [conn.laddr[1] for conn in psutil.net_connections()]:
                self.port = port_candidate
                break

        if self.port in [conn.laddr[1] for conn in psutil.net_connections()]:
            raise IOError('Port ' + str(self.port) + ' is already in use.')
```

Replace by this line:

```
        self.port = 9999
```

Source: https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp/issues/26#issuecomment-445507811

Another solution is to run StanfordCoreNLP with a sudo command line.